# Showing optional value as 'nil' while changing the viewController from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I'm trying to display details from a table row onto another viewController, there are three entities which I want to display on the second VC. Two UILabel and one UIImageView. While in the first VC I'm able to view, when in the second VC, it says 'Optional("")', And don't know how to unwrap it.

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var nameForUser: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var loginButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!




let allEvents = Events.allEvents
var nextScreenRow: Events!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //nameForUser.text! = "Please Enter Name Here"
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //let userName = nameForUser.text

}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.text = ""
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.allEvents.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("eventsCell")!
    let event = self.allEvents[indexPath.row]
    //print(" row \(indexPath.row)")

    cell.textLabel?.text = event.eventName
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: event.imageName)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = event.entryType
    //cell.textLabel?.text = allEvents[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    nextScreenRow = allEvents[indexPath.row]

    let view : DetailedEventViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("trytry") as! DetailedEventViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)

    print("Selected section \(indexPath.section), row \(indexPath.row)")
    print(nextScreenRow.eventName)

    view.eventDetails = nextScreenRow.eventName
    print(view.eventDetails)

    view.typeOfEvent = nextScreenRow.entryType
    view.myImage = UIImage(named: nextScreenRow.imageName)
  //even the 'print' is used, it is displaying here, but not in the next VC  

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.allEvents.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let sec = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("eventsSec", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GridCollectionViewCell

    let event = self.allEvents[indexPath.row]

     sec.imageView.image = UIImage(named: event.imageName)

     sec.caption.text = event.entryType

    return sec
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("tryToConnect2", sender: self)
}






override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "successfulLogin"){
        segue.destinationViewController as! TabController
        //let userName = nameForUser.text
        //controller.userName = userName

    }

}



@IBAction func loginButtonWhenPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let userName = nameForUser.text

    if userName == "" {
        let nextController = UIAlertController()
        nextController.title = "Error!"
        nextController.message = "Please enter a name"

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            action in self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

        nextController.addAction(okAction)
        self.presentViewController(nextController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

}

And here is my second VC:

```
import UIKit

class DetailedEventViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var deatiledEvent: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var eventType: UILabel!

var eventDetails = ""
var typeOfEvent = ""
var myImage: UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func viewTheElemnts(sender: AnyObject) {

    deatiledEvent.text = eventDetails
    print(deatiledEvent.text)

    eventType.text = typeOfEvent
    imageView.image = myImage
}

}
```

Help would be appreciated greatly. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please remove the comments from your code if they are unnecessary and shorten the amount of code you posted to the most relevant part?

Comment: I have edited it, having a problem in the 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'. Thank you.

Comment: @shravan.sukumar: I didn't understand the issue you are facing ? Did you called the `viewTheElements:` IBAction ? Are you getting the correct data in that method ?

Comment: @MidhunMP, I did call the action, and it does not function properly. It changes the labels to blank and also the imageview goes blank. Basically nothing is being displayed.

Comment: @shravan.sukumar: Did you have a segue connected between your tableview and detail page ?

Comment: If your issue is that the data come as an optional then you need to unwrap it using '!'

Comment: @MidhunMP yes, there is. It has an identifier 'trytry'.

Comment: @shravan.sukumar: Remove that segue and check it again

Comment: @MidhunMP the problem is that when I print out the value from the action 'viewTheElements', in the run box, it shows Optional(""), and not any value inside.

Comment: @MidhunMP yes, tried it. It does not move to that VC.

Comment: @shravan.sukumar: Got the issue. Writing an answer, please check it

Comment: Can you add this and check it:



view.eventDetails = nextScreenRow.eventName! as String
        print(view.eventDetails)
        
        view.typeOfEvent = nextScreenRow.entryType
        view.myImage = UIImage(named: nextScreenRow.imageName)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an instance of `DetailedEventViewController` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and setting the value there. But actually you are moving to `DetailedEventViewController` using segue. So you should add those values in the `prepareForSegue:` method.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
   if (segue.identifier == "trytry")
   {
       let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)
       nextScreenRow     = allEvents[selectedIndex.row]
       let view          = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailedEventViewController    
       view.eventDetails = nextScreenRow.eventName
       view.typeOfEvent  = nextScreenRow.entryType
       view.myImage      = UIImage(named: nextScreenRow.imageName)
   }
}
```

Comment: After that what you've asked me to, in the 'prepareForSegue' method when I do it, shows 'fatal error: nil found wile unwrapping optional'

Comment: @shravan.sukumar: On which line you are getting that crash ?

Comment: The line 'view.eventDetails = nextScreenRow.eventName'

Comment: But, I've already define 'nextScreenRow' in the 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath', and it is not allowing me to define it in this function.

Comment: @shravan.sukumar: What you mean by *not allowing to define* ?

Comment: That was a typo in my code when pasted your code. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Unwrap your eventName like this :

```
view.eventDetails = nextScreenRow.eventName! as String 
print(view.eventDetails) view.typeOfEvent = nextScreenRow.entryType 
view.myImage = UIImage(named: nextScreenRow.imageName) 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true
```

Comment: Still not working, it shows 'Optional("")' in the run box.